# SQL query returns result set of 100 but I only need the top 32, how to accomplish this query with input parameter, and have it work in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

This query returns 100 rows:

```
select  distinct(c.id),
        a.zipcode,
        a.city

from client c
    join address a on a.id = c.id
    join [dbo].[View_Members_Only] as v on v.id = c.id

where c.physician_id = '200'
    and
    c.dreendate between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

I only need it to return xx number of rows based on an input parameter.

Tried this but it returns zero rows:

```
declare @startdate date
declare @enddate date
declare @allowedgrantmembers int
set @startdate = '09-01-2023'
set @enddate = '09-3-2023'
set @allowedgrantmembers = 32

/*************************************
parameters for testing purposes only
*************************************/

select top (@allowedgrantmembers)
        c.id,
        a.zipcode,
        a.city

from client c
    join address a on a.id = c.id
    join [dbo].[View_Members_Only] as v on v.id = c.id

where c.physician = '100'
    and
    c.dreendate between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Thank you for help and suggestions.

Comment: Note that `distinct`isn't a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `select distinct` will give you distinct _rows_. Simply write `select distinct c.id, a.zipcode, ...` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER MIND!!

Typo's are a bad thing. I fixed the date range.

Amazing when you can't even see your own mistakes.

When the end date parameter was keyed correctly as the last day of the month, my query worked fine. #embarrassed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).